# Cannot slice DatetimeIndex using the datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, slice

I create a dataframe indexed by a datetime object and the index becomes a DatetimeIndex.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from dateutil.parser import parse
import pandas as pd 

datestr=["2021/2/3","2021/01/6","2021/2/4","2021/2/7","2021/2/7","2021/2/9"]
time_data_2=pd.DataFrame({"data_1":[0.3,0.4,0.9,0.5,0.3,0.3],"data_2":[1,2,3,4,5,6]},index=pd.to_datetime(datestr))
```

I want to slice it using datetime object. But then error comes.

```
time_data_2.loc[datetime(2021,2,1):datetime(2021,2,7),]
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates()

pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._maybe_get_bool_indexer()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._unpack_bool_indexer()

KeyError: 1612137600000000000

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    685         try:
--> 686             return Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    687         except KeyError as err:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 

KeyError: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-db7af75f07ac> in <module>
      1 time_data_2=pd.DataFrame({"data_1":[0.3,0.4,0.9,0.5,0.3,0.3],"data_2":[1,2,3,4,5,6]},index=pd.to_datetime(datestr))
----> 2 time_data_2.loc[datetime(2021,2,1):datetime(2021,2,7),]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    887                     # AttributeError for IntervalTree get_value
    888                     return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
--> 889             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
    890         else:
    891             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   1067             return self._multi_take(tup)
   1068 
-> 1069         return self._getitem_tuple_same_dim(tup)
   1070 
   1071     def _get_label(self, label, axis: int):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple_same_dim(self, tup)
    773                 continue
    774 
--> 775             retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
    776             # We should never have retval.ndim < self.ndim, as that should
    777             #  be handled by the _getitem_lowerdim call above.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1100         if isinstance(key, slice):
   1101             self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1102             return self._get_slice_axis(key, axis=axis)
   1103         elif com.is_bool_indexer(key):
   1104             return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_slice_axis(self, slice_obj, axis)
   1134 
   1135         labels = obj._get_axis(axis)
-> 1136         indexer = labels.slice_indexer(
   1137             slice_obj.start, slice_obj.stop, slice_obj.step, kind="loc"
   1138         )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py in slice_indexer(self, start, end, step, kind)
    782 
    783         try:
--> 784             return Index.slice_indexer(self, start, end, step, kind=kind)
    785         except KeyError:
    786             # For historical reasons DatetimeIndex by default supports

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in slice_indexer(self, start, end, step, kind)
   5275         slice(1, 3, None)
   5276         """
-> 5277         start_slice, end_slice = self.slice_locs(start, end, step=step, kind=kind)
   5278 
   5279         # return a slice

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in slice_locs(self, start, end, step, kind)
   5474         start_slice = None
   5475         if start is not None:
-> 5476             start_slice = self.get_slice_bound(start, "left", kind)
   5477         if start_slice is None:
   5478             start_slice = 0

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_slice_bound(self, label, side, kind)
   5394             except ValueError:
   5395                 # raise the original KeyError
-> 5396                 raise err
   5397 
   5398         if isinstance(slc, np.ndarray):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_slice_bound(self, label, side, kind)
   5388         # we need to look up the label
   5389         try:
-> 5390             slc = self.get_loc(label)
   5391         except KeyError as err:
   5392             try:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    686             return Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    687         except KeyError as err:
--> 688             raise KeyError(orig_key) from err
    689 
    690     def _maybe_cast_for_get_loc(self, key) -> Timestamp:

KeyError: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00')
```

Comment: you can simply use strings; `time_data_2.loc["2021-02-01":"2021-02-07",]`

Comment: The problem is here is that your index is `pandas.Timestamp` objects and you're trying to slice with `datetime.datetime` objects.

Comment: I know it but I tried add .timestamp() after the datetime object and use it to slicing. It still fails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the index isn't sorted, so you can't properly slice on a date range.  It's not a great error message from pandas.  See here:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5821

So, to fix your example:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from dateutil.parser import parse
import pandas as pd 

datestr=["2021/2/3","2021/01/6","2021/2/4","2021/2/7","2021/2/7","2021/2/9"]
time_data_2=pd.DataFrame({"data_1":[0.3,0.4,0.9,0.5,0.3,0.3],"data_2":[1,2,3,4,5,6]},index=pd.to_datetime(datestr))

time_data_2 = time_data_2.sort_index()  # I only added this

time_data_2.loc[datetime(2021,2,1):datetime(2021,2,7),]  # now this works
```